# Deleted posts don't seem to be completely removed

Tags: google-search, search-engines, cache, search-results, url-removal

I asked a webmaster to remove some posts on his website where some pictures and content referring to me appeared.
He removed pictures and content but they still appear as results on google search, and when I click on them I am redirected to some different posts rather than the "*page not found*".

I tried to delete those search results by using the [Google Remove Outdated Content Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals) but the tool says that the webpages are still alive (even if they are no longer there: if I click on the URL I get different pages and content, even if the URL is the same).

For the Google Remove Outdated Content Tool didn't work, I wonder if the posts will be removed from search engine results in the future (I want my pictures and content to be invisible on search engines results too, not only on the website) or if I the webmaster didn't delete them properly?

Comment: Are the image URLs now redirecting or giving "not found" errors?   You should check on the image URLs as well as on the page URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Google says on their [support page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7041154?hl=en):

> Google will remove the snippet and cached copy from search results. If
>   the page is no longer available , it will remove the search result
>   entirely. If the page is still available , it will remove the
>   currently cached version and snippet from search results.

Because the webmaster has redirected the URLs to other posts, the Google Remove Outdated Content Tool will only remove cached content because the URL is redirecting another post. This may take a few days to complete.

To review the exact steps that you need to take to remove an outdated page description or cache I have included it below:

> Follow the instructions below if the short description of the page in
>   search results (the snippet) or the cached version of the page is out
>   of date.
>
> 1. Go to the Remove outdated content page.
> 2. In the "Enter URL of outdated content" box, paste the URL of the page. (Learn how to find the URL of the page)
> 3. Click Request removal.
> 4. If you see “Has the site owner updated or removed the content,” select Yes.
> 5. Select The snippet and cache are outdated.
> 6. Explain exactly what is outdated about the snippet or page. In this box, enter in a word that is on the old version of the page from
>      Google’s search results that is not on the current version of the
>      page. For example, the cached page might show your name, which isn’t
>      in the new version. In this case, don’t write "my name has been
>      removed," but instead type your name as it appears in the cached
>      version.
> 7. Click Request Removal.

**Still seeing the offending content?**

If this still doesn't have the desired effect, **ask the webmaster to remove the redirect to the new post**, so that the old URL returns a "Page Not found" error. In my experience this method is the most sure, and usually removes the URL and all the page content within a few days at most.

Comment: thank you, I followed the steps below. How long does it take for the outdated content to be removed -if the method works-?

Comment: Usually only a few days at most, as mentioned in the answer. the tip down the bottom... "ask the webmaster to remove the redirect to the new post, so that the old URL returns a "Page Not found" error." is the most sure method so I'd recommend you do that.

Comment: Hey @franz1 if this answer resolved your problem, please set it as the accepted answer so others can see it was useful to you. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Hi @garth, the webmaster actually didn't remove the redirect to the new posts, anyhow the content referring to me finally disappeared from the Google search results, so it's ok for me, thanks!